# How to percentage for unique count of string in redshift?

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have my data in the below format:

```
TASK, STATUS
MKw11sk, OPEN
JIKL, CLOSED
pp,DELETED
qwert,PRESENT
DDF,OPEN
```

I am trying to find the percent by status. i wants to know the percentage for status column

i'm newbie to this! Normally i can calculate percentage for integer type values and i dont have to calculate this unique count of string

Answer (score 0):

Was the question *What is the percentage for each status value in the table*?
You can use window function and get the correct value for each row, like this:

```
with input (TASK, STATUS) as (
SELECT 'MKw11sk', 'OPEN' UNION ALL
SELECT 'JIKL', 'CLOSED' UNION ALL
SELECT 'pp', 'DELETED' UNION ALL
SELECT 'qwert', 'PRESENT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'DDF', 'OPEN'
    )
select *,
   count(STATUS) over (partition by STATUS) * 100 / count(STATUS) over () as status_percent
from input;
```

returns

| task | status | status_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JIKL | CLOSED | 20 |
| MKw11sk | OPEN | 40 |
| DDF | OPEN | 40 |
| qwert | PRESENT | 20 |
| pp | DELETED | 20 |

Alternatively you can use a plain `GROUP BY` like this:

```
with input (TASK, STATUS) as (
    SELECT 'MKw11sk', 'OPEN' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'JIKL', 'CLOSED' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'pp', 'DELETED' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'qwert', 'PRESENT' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DDF', 'OPEN'
)
select STATUS,
       count(*) * 100 / (select count(*) from input) as status_percent
from input
group by 1
```

returns

| status | status_percent |
| --- | --- |
| DELETED | 20 |
| OPEN | 40 |
| PRESENT | 20 |
| CLOSED | 20 |

Comment: Is this possible to calculate without give total count(name) of tablename from input

Comment: But how do you want to calculate the percentage without knowing the total count? isn't that the definition of a percent - _ratio of value to total count as a fraction of 100_?

Comment: Maybe explain better what do you want to calculate (with examples) and then it will be easier to provide a helpful example